# Declare array but do not physically allocate it

Tags: c, arrays, linker, allocation

I don't know if this is possible but im trying to define but don't allocate(declare) an array, basically because I need to keep compatibility with already existing code that uses tridimensional arrays.
This "array" is at all effects a pointer to a specific memory address where I mapped the video memory of an external graphics controller, obiviously I could declare a pointer to my specific address memory:

```
unsigned int* PlaneSecondary = (unsigned int*)_Lime_PPC_Base_;
```

But in this way i should access to PlaneSecondary via pointers arithmetic and my pre-existent code doesn't do it.

I managed to define and declare an array in a specific absolute address:

```
#pragma push
#pragma section ".LIME_Plane_section" ".LIME_Plane_section"
unsigned int __attribute__((section (".LIME_Plane_section"))) PlaneSecondary[_Lime_n_layers][_Lime_Y_res][_Lime_X_res];
#pragma pop
```

a portion of .lcf:

```
 lime_mem  : origin = 0x60000000, length = 0x01000000 //16MB ram LIME R/W
 /* .... */
 .LIME_Plane_section 0x60000000 : 
     { 
     } > lime_mem
```

But in this way compiler does physically allocate some space for my PlaneSecondary when I actually don't need it.

If this is possible i guess i missed something in .lcf or some attribute on PlaneSecondary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use array indexing syntax with pointers, just as you can use pointer arithmetics with arrays.

Comment: You could declare the array `extern`. Have the linker deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define pointer to arrays:

```
unsigned int (*PlaneSecondary)[_Lime_Y_res][_Lime_X_res] = (void*)_Lime_PPC_Base_;
```

And then you can access it as:

```
PlaneSecondary[layer][y][x]
```